# How to delete multiple matching rows in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, delete-row

I have a following definition in my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @DeletedRoleTag table( Role_key bigint, Tag_key bigint)
```

E.G. @DeletedRoleTag

```
Role_key    Tag_key
   1           2
   3           4
```

Now from my sql table (RoleTag) I want to delete rows which has matching rows with `@DeletedRoleTag`.

If there exist a row in RoleTag table with Role_key = 1 and Tag_key = 2 or Role_key = 3 and Tag_key = 4 it needs to be deleted.
How do I do this?

Comment: You should tag your questions with the database you are using.  It looks like SQL Server based on the use of a table variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with an `exists` clause:

```
delete from RoleTag rt
   where exists (select 1
                 from @DeletedRoleTag drt
                 where drt.Role_key = rt.Role_key and
                       drt.Tag_key = rt.Tag_key
                );
```

Comment: it's missing the "@" in DeletedRoleTag, additionally the delete from table cannot be alliased, unless you're doing the "double from" syntax

Comment: Thanks! Yep those two changes were required. :)

Comment: @YuvrajSolanki I give up on trying to correct the answer, the edit has been rejected several times now even though it's a valid edit - there was a comment below in my answer that said it was invalid as well but it is completely valid :/

Comment: @Kritner . . . I made the change.  Sometimes (often ?), comment reviews see such a small change and think it is irrelevant -- rather than realizing that it is really fixing a typo.  Perhaps a comment along with the change that says "Fixing a typo that breaks the syntax" would get such changes accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
delete
from roleTag
from roleTag rt
inner join @DeletedRoleTag drt ON rt.role_key = drt.role_key
    and rt.tag_key = drt.tag_key
```

Comment: @Serpiton for SQL Server this is completely valid syntax. Have you tried it?  If you want to alias your delete from table you cannot do it as "delete from roleTag rt" it has to be "delete from roleTag from roleTag rt"